# Rails: Return a 401?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I'd like to return a HTTP 401 error as part of my `permission_denied` method for [declarative_authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization).

```
# triggered when a user accesses a page that they don't have access to
def permission_denied
  # render my default 401 error page?
end
```

How would I do this? (Pardon the question if it's stupid... I know how to render the 401.html page in my public directory, but I don't think it returns the 401 HTTP header, which is what I'm after.)

Comment: A full list of statuses can be found here: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/10/13/list-of-rails-status-code-symbols/

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can add the `:status` option

```
def permission_denied
  render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized
end
```

Comment: Add `:layout => false` to make the page cleaner

Comment: Passing the format in the filename is evidently deprecated, so the new way would be `render :file => "public/401", :status => :unauthorized`.

Comment: The Status like :not_found can be found here <http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render>

Comment: You can also ```render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized``` if you don't want to render any file or text or template or...

Comment: or `head :unauthorized` for no content

Comment: As of Rails 5, rendering with :nothing is deprecated: ```DEPRECATION WARNING: `:nothing` option is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use `head` method to respond with empty response body.```

Answer (score 10):

Here so you don't have to dig through comments for a modern answer.

The previous answer has been deprecated in Rails 5.1

Throw any of these into your controller action:

### Render A File/Template

```rb
render :file => "public/401", :status => :unauthorized
```

### Render JSON

```rb
render status: :unauthorized, json: { error: "You are not authorized to access this resource. Verify that you are passing passing your token." }
```

### Render Nothing

```rb
head :unauthorized
```

[See ActionController#head](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head)